# nHibernate com mais de um banco de dados

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Olá, gostaria de saber se é possível utilizar o nHibernate com mais de um banco de dados, algumas tabelas ficarão em um banco e outras em outro.

Como eu faria isso?

E nos mapeamentos das entidades, como eu informaria que aquele mapeamento é de um tabela de um determinado banco?

Comment: Dá uma olhada [aqui](http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2009/03/30/using-nhibernate-with-multiple-databases/) e [aqui](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14846/Using-NHibernate-with-Multiple-Databases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O mapeamento de suas Entidades seriam os mesmos, porém cada SGBD possui um arquivo de configuração com as connections strings, providers de conexão, etc...

EX: usando Postgres:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.NpgsqlDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost;database=northwind;User Id=postgres;password=123456</property>        
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

No código:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

configuration.Configure("conpgsql.config");
```